# Odd behaviour in Google Web Speech API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, webspeech-api

I'm working with Google's [Web Speech API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk-Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API) using Google Chrome (55.0.2883.87) and I'm experiencing some **very weird** behaviour.

When attempting to speak out names, followed by a number (like `John 4`) it usually just speaks out the name and the number, **as it should** - but for some names it puts the word `chapter` between the name and the number, so `Daniel 4` becomes `Daniel Chapter 4`.

I have picked up some random names and tested them with the following code:

```html
<script>
var names = ['Brian', 'John', 'Mike', 'Julia', 'Daniel', 'Michael', 'David', 'Jason', 'Jack'];

names.forEach(function(name) {
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(name + ' 4');
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
});
</script>
```

The `msg` variable doesn't include the word chapter when logging it with `console.log()`

Of these 9 names, the names `John` and `Daniel` are spoken with the word `chapter` between them.

#### Question

Why does this happen, and which criteria determines which names are affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that one of [your homonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_(biblical_figure)) wrote something in a famous book, and a certain John did too. I would guess that it does the same for Jeremiah or [these others](https://www.google.com/search?q=Josu%C3%A9&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab#q=bible+writers).

But I can't repro neither on my 55.0.2883.95 nor on my 57.0.2954.0 on mac...

Maybe it was a *Christmas Easter egg*.

<sub>so many religious parts in this answer...</sub>

Comment: Lol Easter eggs in Web API , this is something! just like the answer

Comment: Confirmed that it also puts in `chapter` with *Jeremiah*

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is an "Easter Egg":
Generally, speech synthesis engines often try to interpret text fragments in some meaningful way, e.g. reading numbers with punctuation as dates, if that fragment "looks" like a date.

**Explanation**

With Google, I would guess that they heavily rely on statistics for deciding, if a text fragment should be interpreted one way or the other.

In practice this may fail for specific cases, for several reasons: e.g. if the specific case really is some specialized case; if there is not enough "context" to derive the correct/intended meaning (this may be especially true for very short sentences/fragments); if the (text) corpus for deriving the statistics is not balanced w.r.t. common use...

**Suggestion**

Depending on the engine, the behavior often can be somewhat controlled, by formatting the input text differently.

E.g. testing your code snippet in Chrome: if you write out the number (`"four"` instead of `4`), or insert a comma after the name (i.e.`name + ', 4'`), then the speech engine will not insert `"chapter"` (*note that comma also introduces a short pause*).